# What elements kill $1-\zeta_n$ in the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer not congruents to $2$ modulo $4$, also not a prime power.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
A fact that I know is $n({\sigma_i}-{\sigma_{-i}})$ and $\sum_{\sigma \in G}{\sigma}$  kill $(1-\zeta_n)$ where $\sigma_i$ is the map sending $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_{n}^i$.

I wonder if there are any other types of elements except those.

Help me please.

Comment: This is hilbert 90's additive form. For cyclic, traceless objects are exactly generated by $(1-\sigma)$

Comment: @user45765 : I might have caused you confusion. I used those terms(ex: kill) in multiplicative sense not additive.

Comment: That is fine as well. You also have multiplicative form hilbert 90 which is in similar spirit. Since the group is cyclic, you can write down the element of norm 1. Note that for $n$ not being a prime power, $1-\eta_n$ is a unit in number ring.

Comment: @A_yamato   If you "kill" elements of the field in the multiplicative sense, then how does the norm  kill $1-\zeta$ ?

Comment: @user45765 but the galois group is not cyclic in general if $n$ is not a prime power. I don't know how to apply Hilbert's thm 90

Comment: @A_yamato  Sorry, I missed the hypothesis that $n$ is not a prime power

Comment: @A_yamato Sorry. I misread the statement. For that, there is concrete description for hilbert 90 for N(x)=1 with kernel of the norm map. You can look up multiplicative hilbert 90 thm that will concretely describe the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to @user45765, I doubt that the classical proof of Hilbert's thm.90 could give an easy hold on the kernel of the norm in the general case. Let $K/k$ be a finite Galois extension of fields with group $G$. I stick to your notations, which are additive in the group algebra $\mathbf Z[G]$ resp. multiplicative in the group $K^*$. The norm $N$ is the sum of all $\sigma\in G$. Introduce the *augmentation* map $\alpha: \mathbf Z[G] \to \mathbf Z$ which associates to an element of $\mathbf Z[G]$ the sum of its coefficients; Ker $\alpha:=I_G=I$ is called the augmentation ideal, which is easily shown to be generated by the elements $\sigma-1$ for all $\sigma \in G$. If $G=<s>$ is *cyclic*, then $I.K^*$ is just the subgroup of $K^*$ consisting of all $\sigma(x)/x$ for all $x\in K^*$, and the usual Hilbert's 90 can be rewritten as Ker $N=I.K^*$. Its generalization to all $G$, which is of a cohomological nature, states that $H^1(G, K^*)=0$, but unfortunately $H^1(G, K^*)\neq Ker N/I.K^*:=H^{-1}(G, K^*)$ (if you don't know about cohomology groups, just take these as notational "black boxes"), the equality between $H^1$ and $H^{-1}$ occurs if $G$ is cyclic, but not always. All one can add in general is that the order $g$ of $G$ kills all the cohomology groups $H^j (G,A)$ for any $G$-module $A$ and any $j\neq0$ (see e.g. Serre, *"Local Fields"*, chap.8, §3 ; for $j=0$, the group $H^0$ needs to be modified), so in particular $gKer N$ is contained in $I.K^*$.

Using class-field theory, one can go a bit further when dealing with non archimedean local fields or with number fields. In the latter case, add the hypothesis that the real places of $k$ do not split in $K$ (this corresponds to your condition that $n\neq 2$ mod $4$). If $G$ is *abelian*, one can describe explicitly $H^{-1}(G, K^*)$ in terms of $G$ alone. More precisely, let us decompose $G$ as $Z_1 \times Z_2 \times...\times Z_m$, where the groups $Z_j$ are cyclic of orders $n_j$, with $n_j\mid n_{j-1}$ (this is unique up to isomorphism). Writing $A_j= Z_j \times Z_{j+1} \times...\times Z_m$, the main result is an isomorphism of groups $H^{-1}(G, K^*) \cong A_2 \times A_3\times ...\times A_m$, see e.g. thm.1 of the report www.numdam.org/article/SDPP_1975-1976__17_2_A20_0.pdf. This implies that the order of $Z_2$ kills $H^{-1}(G, K^*)$. Another corollary is that $H^1(G, K^*)=H^{-1}(G, K^*)$ iff $G$ is cyclic.

Let us now study the determination (in principle!) of the set $Ann_{\Lambda}(x)=Ann(x)$ of annihilators of a given $x\in Ker N$. This is actually a two-sided ideal of $\Lambda$. For clarity, let us first solve the case of a cyclic extension $K/k$ with group  $G=<\sigma>$. Then any $x\in KerN$ can be written as $x=(\sigma -1)y$, where $y\in K^*$ is defined up to multiplication by a factor in $k^*$. An annihilator $\alpha \in Ann(x)$ is characterized by $\alpha (\sigma-1)y=1$, or $(\sigma-1)(\alpha(y))=1$ by commutativity, or $\alpha(y)\in k^*$. In the case of an *abelian* extension of local fields or number fields as above, let $Z_j=<\sigma_j>$. For $x\in Ker N$, we saw that   $x^{a_2}$ can be written as a product $\prod (\sigma_j -1)y_j$, with $y_j \in K$, hence $(\prod (\sigma_j -1)\alpha(y_j)^{a_2})=1$ as before, but this sole equation does not suffice to conclude, we need to know some relations between the $y_j$. These should be provided by the explicit description of the groups $A_j$ in the lemma after thm.2.2 of the report cited above, which deals explicitly with the case of a bicyclic extension. Of course things should be simpler in your particular case of a non cyclic cyclotomic field  ./.